# Hosting a C# Click Once desktop application online

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've had a C# desktop application developed for a customer that basically simplifies a Magento back end down to just the functionality she needs, as she found Magento too complicated. She uses an older mac, however, so running the tool in a VM proved to be too laggy.

I'm thus looking to host it in the cloud, but have been somewhat overwhelmed by the options available. From my research, Amazon EC2 with XenApp installed via the Amazon Marketplace seems to be a recommended choice. Would you agree? I've looked into AppHarbor as well, but unless I'm wrong I don't think they're able to host desktop apps.

The only potential constraints are that the application needs to make outbound connections over HTTP to the Magento back end and it also issues outbound SQL calls direct to the Magento database. In addition, it's only for one user so the cheaper the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper and less painful to simply buy a little Windows notebook for that purpose? If that customer is using a Mac and you're a Windows developer, maybe it's time you bought a Mac and learned some Mac development? :-)

Comment: ClickOnce applications are *desktop* applications. They aren't *hosted*, they are deployed to desktops so this question doesn't make much sense. Either you are asking how to create a VM with your application on the cloud (far too expensive, more than a new laptop/tablet), or how to store the clickonce files to some cloud storage, so the client's deployment can be easily updated.

Comment: Not to mention, that a management tool for a Web eCommerce site should probably be a web application itself, not a desktop application

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Panagiotis, your second comment really gives me the answer that I need. I was hoping there'd be a cheap cloud based VM solution, or some sort of affordable shared virtual desktop that would allow me to host the app and her to login and access it. I realise now a web app would have been a better option, but the developer says the requirements of the app were too great for a web app. She uses the mac for her other day to day running of the website and store so using an entirely new computer for that purpose is kind of out the question too.

Comment: So you're gonne to write a web app for simplifying another web app? Seriously? How hard can be to learn how to do a couple of stuff within the Magento Admin?